# How can I tap on a UICollectionView cell of a collection view in UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, cells

How can I tap on a UICollectionView cell of a collection view in UIAutomation?

I tried this

```
var iconsCollView = window.collectionViews()[0];
var iconRect = iconsCollView.cells()[0].rect();
var iconX = iconRect.origin.x/100;
var iconY = iconRect.origin.y/100;
iconsCollView.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x: iconX, y: iconY}});
```

but it taps another cell in the collection view, a wrong cell other than the cell I specified its offset.

Can you please help me? is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`UIAElement`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/rect) class reference:

> Your script should treat the rect object as a generic JavaScript object whose properties for origin, x, y, size, width, and height correspond to those of the analogous CGRect Cocoa structure. The rect object has the form {origin:{x:xposition,y:yposition}, size:{width:widthvalue, height:heightvalue}}. The relevant coordinates are screen-relative and are adjusted to account for device orientation.

From the same source under [`tapWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/tapWithOptions) method:

> You can use offsets to achieve finer precision in specifying the hitpoint within the rect for the specified element. The offset comprises a pair of x and y values, each ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. These values represent, respectively, relative horizontal and vertical positions within the rect, with {x:0.0, y:0.0} as the top left and {x:1.0, y:1.0} as the bottom right. Thus, {x:0.3, y:0.6} specifies a position just below and to the left of center, and {x:1.0, y:0.5} specifies a position centered vertically at the far right.

---

From the source you provided, you're trying to tap inside of collection view passing some weirdly scaled offset coordinates of one of its cells (instead of expected *relative horizontal and vertical positions within the rect* of collection view).

If you want to tap the cell simply locate it and call the [`tap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/tap) method on it:

```
var iconsCollView = window.collectionViews()[0];
var iconCellToTap = iconsCollView.cells()[0].tap();
```